# Express not receive data from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, express

This is expressJS code that on localhost server.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("../../03 AngularJS/99_Motorcycle_Angular"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post("/cut_tag", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Data Coming..");
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send("OK");
});
module.exports = app;
```

And this is angularjs code that I test send data to localhost server. (4 Styles)

```
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/cut_tag',"54")
.success(function (data) {alert(data);} );

$http.post('http://localhost:3000/cut_tag',{t:"54"})
.success(function (data) {alert(data);} );

$http.post('http://localhost:3000/cut_tag',{'t':"54"})
.success(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});

$http({
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://localhost:3000/cut_tag',
data: "54",
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
}).success(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});

//The Output on Console is 
//Data Coming.. 
//{}
//{}

//Data Coming.. 
//{}
//{}

//Data Coming.. 
//{}
//{}

//Data Coming.. 
//{}
//{}
```

And Angular App alert("OK");
but I do not know why console.log(req.body) do not have data. Thank for help.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I can solve this problem by add limit for size of data to post

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'})); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false}));
```